# Cassandra: How to identify and list the nodes that contain a particular row (replica)?

Tags: cassandra

Setup information:
I have two DataCenters with 5 nodes in each DC.

I understand that each row inserted on to a table is stored based on the data partitioning scheme used; generates the necessary replicas and stores them on other nodes (chooses nodes based on replication strategy) in the cluster. Given a row, is there a way I can find and list all the nodes that contain this row/replica?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Run this on one of the Cassandra nodes:

```
nodetool -h localhost getendpoints <keyspace> <cf> <key>
```

to print the end points that owns the key.

Comment: Thanks Schildmeijer! I have a follow-up on this. I listed the endpoints containing a particular rowkey and then brought down that node. Then I ran the same command to check if it lists one lesser node. Surprisingly it still outputs the node that is currently down. Should I explicitly perform an update before running this command after bringing a node down?

Comment: I put the node down, but I had to remove this node from the cluster for it to take effect. Thanks!